# How to add Valve to Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat-valve

I wrote a Valve for Apache Tomcat by extending org.apache.catalina.valves.ValveBase class and implementing inovoke() method. Now I want to add it to my Tomcat for execution? Please show me the steps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a jar with your Valve class.

Drop this into the $TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder.

Modify the server.xml to add the valve under 
Engine or Host tag as shown below, depending on which level you want it to operate.

```
 <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
 <Valve className="org.whatever.MyCustomValve" />
```

Comment: Thanks. It Works Successfully.