# How to add Valve to Apache Tomcat and make use of the rewrite.config

Tags: tomcat

So in relation to this post: [How to add Valve to Apache Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878385/how-to-add-valve-to-apache-tomcat/58964905#58964905)

I was able to set the Valve inside the `server.xml` file. (Inside the engine)
Now where would I go about placing the `rewrite.config` file?

I tried to place it inside the `WEB-INF` of the file, but that only works if I set the valve inside the `context.xml`, which I don't want to do.

Comment: see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49543741/7748072)

Comment: Do you want to rewrite URLs only within a single application, or across all applications on the same server (or even for applications that don't exist e.g. `/nosuchapp/index.jsp`?

Comment: I want it across all applications on the same server, and I placed the rewrite here:
conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config

I added the Valve tag in server.xml, inside <Engine>, but outside <Host>.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it worked. 
Thanks to Eugène Adell's post above, and some tinkering.

So I placed the valve inside the the Host tag in the server.xml, so:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="somedomain.com">
  <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve"/>
  </Host>
</Engine>
```

Then I placed the rewrite in here:

$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config